# Await without Async in deno framework

Tags: javascript, deno

Deno just released [v1.0](https://deno.land/v1).

When I was checking [getting started](https://deno.land/#getting-started) guild I show some unusual code.

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.50.0/http/server.ts";
const s = serve({ port: 8000 });

console.log("http://localhost:8000/");

for await (const req of s) {
  req.respond({ body: "Hello World\n" });
}
```

If you see for loop there is await without async.

So I'm wondering, is javascript async/await and deno await both are same or it's different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deno supports [`top-level await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) which is currently on stage 3.

> Top-level await enables modules to act as big async functions: With
>   top-level await, ECMAScript Modules (ESM) can await resources, causing
>   other modules who import them to wait before they start evaluating
>   their body.

`top-level await` allows you to initialize a module with asynchronously fetched data.

```js
// my-module.js
const res = await fetch('https://example.com/some-data');
export default await res.json();
```

```js
// some module
import data from './my-module.js';
console.log(data); // { "some": "json" }
```

---

> If you see for loop there is await without async.

Have in mind that `function`s using `await` will still need `async` keyword, even if `top-level await` is supported.

```
function foo() { // async is needed
   const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api/json')
   console.log(res);
}

foo();
```

The above snippet still throws an error.

---

References:

- https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await
- https://2ality.com/2019/12/top-level-await.html
- https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await

Answer (score 3):

Deno implements top-level await.

Top-level await enables developers to use the await keyword outside of async functions. It acts like a big async function causing other modules who import them to wait before they start evaluating their body.

Source: https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await